# Php: Overriding abstract method goes wrong

Tags: php

I think there is a problem in php's OOP implementation.

**EDIT:** Consider more illustrative example:

```
abstract class Animal {

    public $name;

    // public function Communicate(Animal $partner) {}     // Works
    public abstract function Communicate(Animal $partner); // Gives error
}

class Panda extends Animal {

    public function Communicate(Panda $partner) {
        echo "Hi {$partner->name} I'm a Panda";
    }

}

class Human extends Animal {

    public function Communicate(Human $partner) {
        echo "Hi {$partner->name} I'm a Human";
    }

}

$john = new Human(); $john->name = 'John';
$mary = new Human(); $mary->name = 'Mary';
$john->Communicate($mary); // should be ok

$zuzi = new Panda(); $zuzi->name = 'Zuzi';
$zuzi->Communicate($john); // should give error
```

The problem is that when Animal::Communicate is an abstract method, php tells that the following methods are illegal:

"public function  Communicate(Panda $partner)"
"public function  Communicate(Human $partner)"

but when Animal::Communicate is non-abstract but has zero-implementation Php thinks that these methods are legal. So in my opinion it's not right because we are doing override in both cases, and these both cases are equal, so it seems like it's a bug...

**Older part of the post:**

Please consider the following code:

**Framework.php**

```
namespace A
{
    class Component { ... }

    abstract class Decorator {
        public abstract function Decorate(\A\Component $component);
    }
}
```

**Implementation.php**

```
namespace B
{
    class MyComponent extends \A\Component { ... }
}
```

**MyDecorator.php**

```
namespace A
{
    class MyDecorator extends Decorator {
        public function Decorate(\B\MyComponent $component) { ... }
    }
}
```

The following code gives error in **MyDecorator.php** telling

Fatal error: Declaration of MyDecorator::Decorate() must be compatible with that of A\Decorator::Decorate() in MyDecorator.php on line ...

But when I change the Framework.php::Decorator class to the following implementation:

```
    abstract class Decorator {
        public function Decorate(\A\Component $component) {}
    }
```

the problem disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36601, this issues has been reported as a bug but was rejected because of laziness :D

Comment: The problem is that type hints allow specialization in general, but not allow it when the method is abstract, so I suspect that actually they have implemented this functionality since 2006 but forgot something and it bugs when the method is abstract

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure (haven't tested it ;), but you declare this abstract function:

```
public abstract function Decorate(\A\Component $component);
```

So you should implement this EXACTLY like that. But you did this:

```
public function Decorate(\B\MyComponent $component) { ... }
```

That's not the same. Could you try to change that to `\A\Component`?

To all comments: fact of the matter is that this piece of PHP "runs"

```
namespace A
{
    class Component { }

    abstract class Decorator {
        public abstract function Decorate(\A\Component $component);
    }
}
namespace B
{
    class MyComponent extends \A\Component { }
}
namespace A
{
    class MyDecorator extends Decorator {
        public function Decorate(\A\Component $component) {}
    }

}
```

And this doesn't:

```
<?php
namespace A
{
    class Component { }

    abstract class Decorator {
        public abstract function Decorate(\A\Component $component);
    }
}
namespace B
{
    class MyComponent extends \A\Component { }
}
namespace A
{
    class MyDecorator extends Decorator {
        public function Decorate(\B\MyComponent $component) {}
    }

}
?>
```

With this error: `PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of A\MyDecorator::Decorate() must be compatible with that of A\Decorator::Decorate() in line 18`

Now you can discuss all you like about how that should or should not be, but that's the problem with the code.

so, to satisfy my own curiosity: this is illegal too:

```
<?php
    class Component { }

    abstract class Decorator {
        public abstract function Decorate(Component $component);
    }

    class MyComponent extends Component { }
    class MyDecorator extends Decorator {
        public function Decorate(MyComponent $component) {}
    }


?>
```

It's not the namespaces or anything. It just doesn't seem legal.

Comment: This pattern restricts types to more specific ones, it shouldn't be a problem because \B\MyComponent extends \A\Component and this means that \B\MyComponent is the \A\Component in the first place

Comment: But your abstract makes you define a function that accepts ALL `\A\Component` arguments, and your implementation only accepts `\B\MyComponent`. This means that you have not implemented the function that is 'demanded' by the super.

Comment: Nope, Lu4 is right, because a more specific class has to be a subtype and fulfill all requirements that exist for its superclass. It's called Liskow's substitution principle and is and fundamental rule of OOP...

Comment: Maybe it's the namespace, maybe your liskow's substitution principle isn't followd in PHP, but it is still the reason why it doesn't work. see example-edits in my answer.

Comment: Well, I'm not seeing any questions anymore. You have to do it as I posted (so no deriv. class) in PHP. That might be a bug, but it is the situation as it is we agree, right? Don't really know what to add anymore....

Comment: For anyone running into this issue in a later time, This is still true for PHP 7.1

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with it being abstract. It has to do with the type hinting. The two definitions of the method are not compatible because you explicitly set the argument to be of type `\A\Component` and then try to overload the method with `\B\Component` you cant do that because it changes the method signature. Any subsequent declaration of `Decorate` must use the same type hint as its parent declaration in order for the method signatures to be compatible.

Comment: Yes but, \B\Component extends \A\Component, and this means that the signatures are equal in terms of OOP, any way this thing is working when the method has zero-implementation, and when I mark it as abstract and remove zero-implementation, it tells that the methods are not compatible. I don't think that implementation of method is a subject of method signature compatability

Comment: actually it is a subject they messed up in PHP (like many others)... strictly speaking, type hinting with subtypes would have to be possible in an OO language (which PHP in fact is only since a reasonable amount of time)...

Answer (score 0):

This might assist someone, and am not late.
The best way to handle such is by using an interface.
Consider below;

```
<?php
    interface Componentor{}

    class Component implements Componentor { }

    abstract class Decorator {
        public abstract function Decorate(Componentor $component);
    }

    class MyComponent extends Component { }

    class MyDecorator extends Decorator {
        public function Decorate(Componentor $component) {}
    }

?>
```

Usage;

```
<?php
    $c=new Component();
    //TODO ....blah blah blah...
    $decor=new MyDecorator();
    //TODO ....blah blah blah...
    $decor->Decorate($c);

?>
```